# Connect to 3G (yet again)

Tags: networking, usb, internet

I'm trying to connect to a 3G network via a Huawei E173 modem. Thankfully it is getting recognized as a usb modem without me having to deal with modeswitch

```
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 12d1:1436 Huawei Technologies Co., Ltd. Broadband stick
```

Next I installed `wvdial` and set up the config file

```
[Dialer Defaults]
Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
; Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","telenorbg"
Modem Type = Analog Modem
ISDN = 0
New PPPD = yes
Username = { }
Password = { }
Modem = /dev/gsmmodem
; Modem = /dev/ttyUSB0
Dial Command = ATD
Stupid Mode = 1
Phone = 0896182325

; Baud = 115200
; Baud = 3600000
Baud = 9600
```

I've tried any combination of all the settings you see commented and nothing has worked. When I run `sudo wvdial` this is (almost) always the output

```
--> WvDial: Internet dialer version 1.61
--> Initializing modem.
--> Sending: ATZ
ATZ
OK
--> Sending: ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
OK
--> Modem initialized.
--> Sending: ATD0896182325
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATD0896182325
BUSY
--> The line is busy. Trying again.
--> Sending: ATD0896182325
--> Waiting for carrier.
ATD0896182325
^CCaught signal 2:  Attempting to exit gracefully...
--> Disconnecting at Tue Oct 16 19:55:51 2018
```

Is there anything I can do or this stick is just not going to work? I tried it on a windows machine and I had to install a bunch of drivers before it would work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Managed to resolve the issue by changing `Phone` to `*99#`. Final config:

```
[Dialer Defaults]

Init1 = ATZ
Init2 = ATQ0 V1 E1 S0=0 &C1 &D2 +FCLASS=0
Init3 = AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","telenorbg"
Stupid Mode = 1
Modem Type = USB Modem
ISDN = 0
Phone = *99#
; Phone = 0896182322
Modem = /dev/gsmmodem
Username = *
Password = *
New PPPD = yes
; Auto DNS = 1
Baud = 115200
```